# InvalidCastException when using Dapper to map a Date field from MySql

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, dapper

I am just getting started using Dapper to access a MySql database and I seem to be running into an issue when dealing with date fields.  Any time I try to map a MySql Date type field I am receiving an invalid cast.  It seems that the MySql connector is returning a MySqlDateTime type which causes Dapper to cast it to an Object instead of a date time.  Here's the relevant code

Property definition on my model

```
public DateTime PickupDate { get; set; }
```

Field definition in MySql

```
PickupDate DATE
```

Exception Being Thrown

```
System.Data.DataException : Error parsing column 1 (PickupDate= - Object)
----> System.InvalidCastException : Specified cast is not valid.
```

I know it must be something I'm missing, can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I need to do to have dapper map this field to a DateTime data type?

Comment: Hmmm... That's vexing. I could try changing it to use GetDateTime explicitly; are zero-dates going to be a problem? (it depends also on the ZeroDateTimeBehavior in the connection-string)

Comment: zero-dates should not be be a problem.

Comment: After reading your comment, I change the allow zero date time option in the connection string to false and it now works as expected.  Reading the documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-connection-options.html though it seems that even if it is true, it should return a DateTime type for valid dates, but I'm getting the exception instead...

Comment: so is it sorted then? If so, since you found it, do you want to add an answer talking about `AllowZeroDateTime` for the benefit of the next reader? If it isn't, can you clarify the scenario where it fails?

Comment: This takes care of me, but it still does not seem to work as expected, although I think the problem is more related to the way the mysql connector handles it.  What would be nice is if there was some way to extend it so I could have it convert MySqlDateTime types to a nullable DateTime type instead of it just returning it as an object.  None the less, this did solve my issue so I added the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was to set AllowZeroDateTime to false in the connection string.  From the MySql conneciton string options doc found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html).

> If set to True, MySqlDataReader.GetValue() returns a MySqlDateTime object for date or datetime columns that have disallowed values, such as zero datetime values, and a System.DateTime object for valid values. If set to False (the default setting) it causes a System.DateTime object to be returned for all valid values and an exception to be thrown for disallowed values, such as zero datetime values.

For some reason, even with a valid date, I was getting the MySqlDateTime type instead of DateTime.  Changing this to false causes the correct behavior to take place.